# Asp.net core application, ##[error]Error: No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\r1\a\**\*.zip i get this error

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I use ASP.NET core , and i am building a pipeline in Azure DevOps.
The build is successful. but in the release error says:

> [error]Error: No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\r1\a***.zip

I have tried to add these in build pipeline:

```
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
```

But got this warning there:

> [warning]Directory '/home/vsts/work/1/a' is empty. Nothing will be added to build artifact 'drop'.

My Build yaml looks this way:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'Ubuntu-16.04'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- script: dotnet build --configuration $(buildConfiguration)
  displayName: 'dotnet build $(buildConfiguration)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
```

Comment: is this the complete yaml from your build ? you just build something but don't copy it to the $(build.artifactsstagingdirectory)

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let us know if you would like further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

> Asp.net core application, ##[error]Error: No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\r1\a***.zip i get this error

Just as D.J said, you should add another task [Copy Files task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) before the task `PublishBuildArtifacts`.

As the state of the task [Publish Build Artifacts task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops):

> Use this task in a build pipeline to **publish build artifacts** to Azure
>   Pipelines, TFS, or a file share.

But the output of the build task is not automatically copied to the build artifacts, so we need a copy task to copy it to the build artifacts:

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    contents: '_buildOutput\**'
    targetFolder: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    pathtoPublish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
    artifactName: MyBuildOutputs
```

Note: Pay attention to check the syntax of Arguments [Contents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#arguments) in the copy file task.

Hope this helps.